# Простой вопрос по Spring (Java-based configuration)

Tags: spring, java

Учу конфигурацию на основе java кода. В данный момент получился вот такой код:

```
@Autowired
@Bean(name = "validator")
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getLocalValidatorFactoryBean(MessageSource source) {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setValidationMessageSource(source);
    return validator;
}

@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
    return .. // нужно вернуть бин "validator"
}
```

Что делать дальше? Я могу там написать `return getLocalValidatorFactoryBean()`, но тогда в скобках придётся указывать `messageSource`, то есть получается длинная цепочка из зависимостей, что противоречит идеологии Spring. Дописывать аргумент в метод `getValidator` (чтобы использовать `@Autowired`) тоже не круто, потому что тогда получится перегрузка метода (overload), а не переопределение (override).

То есть как бы аналог такой xml-конфигурации:

```
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator"/>
```

Тут я могу дальше в любом месте обращаться к валидатору по id, не таща за собой цепочку его зависимостей.

Comment: А можно уточнить, зачем вам вообще такой метод, тем более в классе конфигурации?

Comment: повторил вот за этим примером  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957878/spring-mvc-bean-validation-with-java-configuration
если подскажете более правильное решение, буду только рад

Comment: Да и в принципе, не только для этого случая, какие ещё способы оперирования с бинами есть?

Comment: Правильнымрешением сейчас будет пойти спать :)

Comment: @Mage, жду вас утром, надеюсь на помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем определять бин отдельно в методе `getLocalValidatorFactoryBean()`? Создавайте его в `getValidator()` и будет меньше лишнего кода и проблем. Если вам при создании понадобится `MessageSource`, то либо а) создавайте его там же (если нигде больше не нужен) б) объявите член класса типа `MessageSource` и инжектите его через `@Autowired`.

(Сам я пошел по пути а.)

Comment: MessageSource нужен в двух местах. А про член класса - гениально.

Comment: Посмотрел свой же код и понял почему мне он не нужен в двух местах -- у меня сообщения для валидаторов находятся в отдельном файле, а локализация интерфейся -- в другом (а для Spring Security так и вовсе в третьем).